# Stabilize Video Rotation

Tags: video, video-editor, software-recommendation, stabilisation, freeware

How would I go about "stabilizing" a video's rotation using freeware / opensourceware?
Please also name that piece of freeware / opensourceware.

Obviously, I do not want to rotate each frame of the video by hand.

See link below for an example of what I mean (65 844 bytes)

http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=08971816374946938459

Answer (score 2):

[Blender](https://www.blender.org/) has a video stabilization feature based on its camera tracker.  Here is a YouTube tutorial on how to use this feature to stabilize a hand-held video:

Answer (score 0):

Well "technically" you could google the download page for Adobe CS6 Production Premium - which includes After Effects.

It allows a free un-restricted 30 day trial.

Import your footage into either Premiere, or preferably After Effects. Apply the Animation Effect "Warp Stabilizer".

It does an amazing job.

But you'll only get 30 days until the software expires or you enter a serial.